# Complex Coupling Strength in Light-Matter Interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, cavity-qed

The quantised electric field operator is given by :

$$ \hat{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},t) = i\sum_{\xi}E_{\xi}\left(\mathbf{u}_{\xi}(\mathbf{r})a_{\xi}-\mathbf{u}^*(\mathbf{r})a_{\xi}^{†}\right) $$

where the complex pre-factor is sometimes absorbed into the mode function $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r})$ such that $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}) = i\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r})$ and therefore:

$$ \hat{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},t) = \sum_{\xi}E_{\xi}\left(\mathbf{f}_{\xi}(\mathbf{r})a_{\xi} + \mathbf{f}^*(\mathbf{r})a_{\xi}^{†}\right) $$

The interaction of a two level quantum system with a single mode of the electric field is then given by $\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}_0,t)$ where $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{D}_{12}\left(\sigma_+ + \sigma_-\right)$ is the dipole operator. The overall interaction can then be written as:

$$ \mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}_0,t) = \left(\sigma_++\sigma_-\right) \left(g_{\xi}a_{\xi} + g_{\xi}^*a^{†}_{\xi}\right)$$

where $g_{\xi}=E_{\xi}\mathbf{D}_{12}\cdot\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r}_0) = iE_{\xi}\mathbf{D}_{12}\cdot\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}_0)$. If the mode is assumed to be a plane wave, $e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$, in the same direction as the dipole moment and $\mathbf{r}_0=0$ then $g_{\xi}=iE_{\xi}|\mathbf{D}_{12}|$.

However, $g_{\xi}$ is usually assumed to be real, so that the interaction hamiltonian can be written in the form $g_{\xi}\left(\sigma_+ + \sigma_-\right)\left(a_{\xi} + a_{\xi}^†\right)$. This doesn't seem to be true here, despite being used all over the place.

I guess my questions are:

(1) Is there a mistake in my logic?

(2) If not, is there a reason the factor of $i$ can be ignored in $g_{\xi}$ and are there any consequence to this?

(3) Also, any other information related to this question would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the ladder operators to absorb the phase. The mapping

$$a \rightarrow e^{i\phi} a$$

is canonical, since it preserves the commutation relations.

So there is no mistake in your logic, but the dynamics only depend trivially on the phase. Note, however, that your Hamiltonian may need to be adapted in certain cases, such as for complex dipole moments.

Comment: Thanks @Wolpertinger, that makes complete sense! I presume this would also be valid for the case of multiple modes, where the canonical transformation is performed for each mode?

Comment: @Angus yes, indeed! The central condition for operator transformations is that the commutators have to stay the same, since they determine the dynamics in the EOMs. You could try checking how this works for multiple modes then. Also: This mapping is in a sense a simple special case of Bogoliubov transformations.